# Multi Station time series forecast of flood through LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I need to make flood forecast for 11 different stations. Each station require different forecast i.e. flood level (water inflow in cusecs) is different for different stations. Can A single LSTM model can handle all stations.
Parameters for all stations are same, like upstream discharge, rain, slope.

Moreover Flood period is only one month or 20 days of a year. If I want to use 10 years of data is there a way to use only 2 months data each year. 1 month with flood
1 month with no flood

But according to my knowledge there should not be any break in time steps in LSTM.

Please guide me your best. i am new to machine learning.

I would be highly thankful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.